# How do I set up the OAuth credentials?

Tags: java, twitter, oauth, twitter4j

How do I set up `OAuth` credentials for `twitter4j`, before I start using it for re tweeting , messaging etc.

I read the documentation but didn't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

- Sign up for a Twitter account at https://twitter.com
- Log in to the Developer Website at https://dev.twitter.com
- Create an app at https://apps.twitter.com/
- Fill in all the details

You will be rewarded with all the OAuth credentials you need.

Comment: I asked, _"..How to set up OAuth credentials for twitter4j"_

Comment: Have you got your OAuth tokens from Twitter? Have you added them in to Twitter4j?

Comment: How to add them in to Twitter4j ? That is what I asked

Comment: I am sorry but I really do not know, what and how to do.